# How does Jimmy greet the women in the parlor?

Tags: better-call-saul

What is the greeting Jimmy uses whenever he enters the parlor to enter his office in *Better Call Saul*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He says: "Chào các cô, ladies", which is Vietnamese for "Hello ladies".

https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Ch%C3%A0o%20c%C3%A1c%20c%C3%B4